# How to use the raw middleware in express

Tags: node.js, express, curl

I tried this snippet of code:

```
//index.js
const express = require("express")

const app = express()

app.post("/", express.raw(), (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    res.write(req.body.toString())
    res.send()
})

app.listen(4000)
```

```sh
curl localhost:4000 -X "POST" -d "foo"
```

If I call the endpoint with curl there is no data in the `req.body`. Where am I wrong? I mean where does the `express.raw` middleware stores the data? In `req.body` doesn't it?

The console output of the program:

```sh
Object {}
```

The curl response:

```sh
[object Object]%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this alternate way. This has the same functionality.

### index.js

```
const express = require("express")

const app = express()
app.use(express.text())
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    res.write(req.body.toString())
    res.send()
})

app.listen(4000)
```

### Curl Command

```
curl localhost:4000 -H "Content-Type:text/plain" -X "POST" -d "foo"
```

### Terminal

```
foo
```

Comment: Yes this is the answer. I had to add the content type and change the middleware to `express.text()`. Thank you.